# React native autocomplete input list is not ovelay over ther inputs properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, autocomplete, frontend

I am using Autocomplete-Input package in react native mobile app. I finished all the functtions properly, but i am facing problem with the styling of the drop suggestions list of Autocomplete. When i am making the list ovelay the other inputs the touchable(suggestions) not working fine.

[This image showing Autocomplete working well but the lsit is pushing the whole design underneath and not overlaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ7zp.png)

[This is the code of the Autocomplete input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gfaw.png)

[This is the style of the Autocomplete input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnhhf.png)

[Here i changed the style to make the list overlaying the other inputs as shown in the next image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYywG.png)

[Here overlaying working fine but the problem is the touchable not working properly, so when i am pressing on any of suggesstions is not selected ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfzwZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to write "zIndex:1" after the "position:absolut".

```
position: "absolute",
elevation: 1,
zIndex: 1,
```